# Use socket.io with ECMA Script modules (ESM)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, socket.io

How do we use socket.io library with ecmascript module syntax?
I'm getting following error if I'm importing it like this:

```
import socketIO from "socket.io";
```

Error:

```
SyntaxError: The requested module 'socket.io' does not provide an export named 'default'
```

Comment: Try import {Socket} from ‘socket.io’. The socket.io package exports a server module as well so a default export won’t work here. You can also do import * as SocketIO from ‘socket.io’. Then you will need to do socketIO.Socket

Comment: Thanks bro @Austin Burger it worked. I wish you could have provided this solution as answer so I could mark it as accepted answer. Thanks a tons

Comment: I have posted the solution as an answer thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
import {Socket} from ‘socket.io’
```

The socket.io package exports a server module as well so a default export won’t work here.

You can also do:

```
import * as SocketIO from ‘socket.io’
```

Then you will need to do socketIO.Socket